# почему mySQL выдаёт ошибку '[err] /*' - т.е. на комментарий?

Tags: mysql

Я так понимаю в версии 5.5.5.9 удалили поддержку комментариев?
Ведь файл дампа у меня начинается как раз с комментария от Navicat'а:

```
/*
бла-бла-бла
*/
[Данные]
```

Загрузка сразу выдаёт: `[err] /* - MySQL server version for the right sintax to use near '/*`

Comment: Можете полный запрос показать

Answer (score 1):

Для комментариев вида `/* comm */` есть некоторые ограничения. Можете посмотреть это в официальной документации:
http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Comments.html